# How to make an interface available via web service?

Tags: c#, service, web, interface, contract

I'm working on .NET, I want to write an interface on web service for my clients(multi client) so they can inherit from my interface to make their own web service, and I can call their web service dynamically.

Is there any way to make it?
Thanks.

Edit:
Because I'm new on web service. I will make it more clear. 
I want all my customer's web sevice have same method. 
I have several cuatomers. I want to have some object or interface from my web site so they can inherit from it. 
I can store their web service's URL to database, and I can call their service dynamically. 
So, how to do it?

Comment: I still cannot get your idea on this, please elaborate more? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I didnt know it was event possible to call a service dynamically just by making them use a certain interface

Comment: Ok, Because I'm new on web service. I will make it more clear. I want my customer's web sevice have same method. I have several cuatomers. I can store their web service's URL to database, and I can call their service dynamically. So, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple, you don't need to do anything in terms of inheritance really, that's the basic premise of web services. 
Just create a dummy web service of your own (You can use this one for testing as well to return test values) and give URL to your customers. 
They can all get the specs (basically they just need to add "?WSDL" at the end of your test web service) and get WSDL which they should implement into their own web service.
If that test web service is internal to your network you can simply get WSDL yourself and email it to them.

Once they all implement this web service, you can just connect to theirs and it will behave exactly the same.